# Haskell Stack: System-wide package cache

Tags: installation, package-managers, haskell-stack

Our school computers have Stack installed, but it's hard to use because user directories have very limited space. I'm wondering if there's a way to have a system-wide `.stack` folder, instead of having it in user directories.

If I found a solution, I could communicate it to our IT people - they have historically been super helpful with user requests.

Comment: Sounds related to [this feature request](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/2205). Feel free to chime in on the issue tracker!